# Laravel public folder subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I have laravel folder like this

- app
- vendor
- bootstrap
- public

  - folder
  - img

when I access from url
http://example.com/img/img.png it works
But when i access like http://example.com/img/ I get Forbidden 403,
What I need is to redirect or to show that page not found
My .htaccess looks like this.

> Options -MultiViews
>           Options -Indexes
>       
>       RewriteEngine On
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.1\.1\.1
> RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> # First rewrite to HTTPS:
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
>  # Handle Front Controller...
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] </IfModule>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my .htaccess to

> Options -MultiViews
>           Options -Indexes
>       
>       RewriteEngine On
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.1\.1\.1
> RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> # First rewrite to HTTPS:
> # Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
> # the subsequent rule will catch it.
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> # Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
>
>  # Handle Front Controller...
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] </IfModule>
> ```

[Source:](http://laravel.io/forum/07-16-2014-redirect-loops-when-viewing-directories)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say setup a simple route like in the routes.php like so:

```
Route::get("/img", function(){
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```

this should do the trick. editing your .htaccess isn't really nessecary unless you really have no other way of doing this kind of things

Comment: didn't helped still the same

Comment: change "/img" to "img", that might solve it and otherwise i need to research it myself on a later time

Comment: hmm strange, i'd suggest posting it on the laravel forums, because this should work.